# I'm working on an app like instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need help posting a picture onto a tableview after i posted to parse. I am using parse and objective-c. I got to where you can post a picture and I can see it on parse, but how can I see the picture on like a timeline in my app or a table view?

Here is my code for posting to parse,

```
- (IBAction)uploadButton:(id)sender{
    NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageView.image, 100);
    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:data];

    // Save the image to Parse

    [imageFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The image has now been uploaded to Parse. Associate it with a new object
            PFObject* newPhotoObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"PhotoObject"];
            [newPhotoObject setObject:imageFile forKey:@"image"];

            [newPhotoObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSLog(@"Saved");
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Your picture has been successfully uploaded." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];

                }
                else{
                    // Error
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

What else do I need to put in order to see what I posted on my main tableview page?

I labeled the view controllers "posting page" and the "main page". The "main page" is where I want all the pictures I post to parse to end up, with a comment section for the picture.

Comment: Can you try like fetch again from Parse once image uploaded and reload the timeline or tableview.

Answer (score -1):

**i have done like this , may be useful to you. take a look**

```
-(IBAction)btnUpDateImageClicked:(id)sender
{
    if (UserSelectedImage)
    {
        HUDSHOWWITHTEXT(@"Updating profile");
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:User_Info];
        NSLog(@"->%@",[PFUser currentUser].username);

        [query whereKey:UserName equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];

        [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * user , NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                // Found User and modify it

                PFFile *imageFile1,*imageFilePlaceHolder;
                NSData *imageData1,*imageDataPlaceHolder;
                //            PFFile *fileDeleted = [[PFFile alloc] init];

                if (UserSelectedImage) {

                    //User image
                    imageData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UserSelectedImage, 1.0);
                    imageFile1 = [PFFile fileWithName:@"img.png" data:imageData1];
                    [user setObject:imageFile1 forKey:@"user_image"];

                    //PlaceHolder
                    UIImage *imagPlaceholder = UserSelectedImage;
                    imagPlaceholder = [APP_DELEGATE SyncPlaceHolderImage:imagPlaceholder];
                    imageDataPlaceHolder = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagPlaceholder, 1.0);
                    imageFilePlaceHolder = [PFFile fileWithName:@"img.png" data:imageDataPlaceHolder];
                    [user setObject:imageFilePlaceHolder forKey:@"placeholder_image"];
                }
                else {
                    user[@"user_image1"] = [NSNull null];
                    user[@"placeholder_image"] = [NSNull null];
                }


                // Save
                [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                    if (succeeded) {
                        HUDHIDE;

                        if (UserSelectedImage) {
                            APP_DELEGATE.user.pfImageOne        =   imageFile1;
                            APP_DELEGATE.user.pfImagePlaceHolder=   imageFilePlaceHolder;
                        }
                        else {
                            APP_DELEGATE.user.pfImageOne = nil;
                            APP_DELEGATE.user.pfImagePlaceHolder=nil;
                        }

                        ShowAlert(@"Saved SUccesfully");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HUDHIDE;
                        ShowAlert(@"Problem updating profile-%@");
                    }
                }];
            } else {
                // Did not find any UserStats for the current user
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                HUDHIDE;
                ShowAlert(@"Problem updating profile")
            }
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        ShowAlert(@"please select Image");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what controller do I put this code in (my posting one or in the main page)? because I get errors, do I have to put something in the h. file or just the m.?

Comment: as per your requirement . modify code and use it as per u needed. i just give how to upload image using parse. you should write this code in .m file in button click method.

Comment: did you find your solution ?

Comment: No not really, I already have the code to upload the picture to parse, where is the code where when I upload to parse it uploads to my main controller on a table view, thats the code I need.

Comment: for that you have to store image , so use SDWebImage Library. and image is store in cache.